# Disable dimmer function and leave on off function

Tags: led, dimmer-switch

I have this dual dimmer in my bedroom controlling two ceiling lamps.
One of the lamps and dimmer never worked by the way.

The working ceiling lamp, led light bulbs flicker even at maximum strengtht. Flicker happens sometimes, mostly in the evening.

This started happening since they refurbished the flat upstairs and used heavy equipment 3 weeks ago interestingly enough. I replaced the 3x led lightbulbs with new ones and flicker as well.

I’d like to disable the dimmer function and leave the switches as on/off in the hope it’ll fix the flickering.

Can you kindly point me to what to change in this setup?

p.s. the working switch in the picture that I would like to disable its dimmer function is the one on the left, the one with the sticker.

Thanks for looking!
Luca

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]

Comment: Sounds to me like your switch is simply not compatible with LED lights—not all are.  Do the lights flicker if you use an incandescent bulb (if you even have one available to try)?

Comment: I don’t know, I only used led lights for the past 5 years. And flickering only started 3 weeks ago. Both old and new led lights flicker. I’d be happy to bypass the dimmer function if you could kindly help me achieving that.

Comment: I tried filament led lights with the same result. It’s odd that the flicker happens on and off throughout the day, as if it were dependent on equipment not linked to my flat.